# How to scrape text from <strong> tag?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

How would I extract the text '01 Jul 00:00' from this element? I am using python requests and BeautifulSoup

```
<div class="plc-product-date___1zgO_ gl-label gl-label--m gl-label--condensed"><strong>Thursday 01 Jul 00:00</strong></div>
```

EDITED Current code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36'}
url = "https://www.adidas.com.sg/release-dates"
productsource = requests.get(url,headers=headers,timeout=15)
productinfo = BeautifulSoup(productsource.text, "lxml")

def jdMonitor():
    #webscraper
    for item in productinfo.find('div', {'class': 'plc-product-list___1Lg2h'}):

        pname = item.find("div", class_='plc-product-name___2cofu gl-product-card__name gl-label gl-label--m gl-label--condensed').get_text(strip=True)                #product title
        price = item.find("div", class_="gl-price-item notranslate gl-label--m").get_text(strip=True)                      #product price
        imagelink = item.find('img')['src']                           #product image link
        plink = f"https://www.adidas.com.sg/{item.a['href']}"                                         #to get product page link
        pdate = item.find("div",class_='plc-product-date___1zgO_ gl-label gl-label--m gl-label--condensed').get_text(strip=True),
        print(pdate)

jdMonitor()
```

Comment: `item.find("div",class_='plc-product-date___1zgO_ gl-label gl-label--m gl-label--condensed').get_text(strip=True)` or `item.find("strong").get_text(strip=True)`

Comment: @RJ Adriaansen  I got an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'`

Comment: Please include your full code in the question, we can't reproduce this error.

Comment: @RJ Adriaansen Just updated code

Answer (score 2):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


item = '<div class="plc-product-date___1zgO_ gl-label gl-label--m gl-label--condensed"><strong>Thursday 01 Jul 00:00</strong></div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(item, 'lxml')
abc = soup.find(name="strong")
print(abc.text)
```

Output:

```
Thursday 01 Jul 00:00
```

Seeing your code, I tried to correct your error:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/'
                         '84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36'}
url = "https://www.adidas.com.sg/release-dates"
productsource = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=15)
productinfo = BeautifulSoup(productsource.text, "lxml")


def jdMonitor():
    # webscraper
    all_items = productinfo.find_all(name="div", class_="gl-product-card")
    # print(all_items)
    for item in all_items:
        # print(item)
        pname = item.find(name="div", class_="plc-product-name___2cofu").text
        pprice = item.find(name="div", class_="gl-price-item").text
        imagelink = item.find(name="img")['src']
        plink = f"https://www.adidas.com.sg/{item.a['href']}"
        try:
            pdate = item.find_all(name="div", class_="plc-product-date___1zgO_").strong.text
        except AttributeError:
            pdate = ""
        print(f"""
        Product Name: {pname}
        Product Price: {pprice}
        Image Link: {imagelink}
        Product Link: {plink}
        Product Date: {pdate}
""")


jdMonitor()
```

This should give output like (Only 1 item shown):

```
Product Name: X Speedflow Messi.1 Firm Ground Boots
Product Price: $400.00
Image Link: https://assets.adidas.com/images/w_512,h_512,f_auto,q_auto:sensitive,fl_lossy,c_fill,g_auto/fcb0489ff2f642c5ad86ad35009947ec_9366/X_Speedflow_Messi.1_Firm_Ground_Boots_Silver_GX0216_01_standard.jpg
Product Link: https://www.adidas.com.sg//x-speedflow-messi.1-firm-ground-boots/GX0216.html
Product Date: Wednesday 30 Jun 21:30
```

You were trying to extract the text inside `<strong>` tag using `item.find("div",class_='plc-product-date___1zgO_ gl-label gl-label--m gl-label--condensed').get_text(strip=True)`, but all the "item" do not contain the `class_='plc-product-date___1zgO_ gl-label gl-label--m gl-label--condensed'` so you were getting a `NoneType` error.
I used a simple try/except block to get over the error and made some small changes around the code.

Comment: would there be a more general way of doing it, I would like to apply the solution to other similar elements with the <strong> tag.

Comment: Hey. I made a few edits. Do check them out, they might help you understand the error.

Comment: I just tried this code, but this time instead of giving the reults like you got, I have all empty lines :(

Answer (score 0):

To get all text inside elements containing class *plc-product-date___1zgO*

```
html = '<div class="plc-product-date___1zgO_ gl-label gl-label--m gl-label--condensed"><strong>Thursday 01 Jul 00:00</strong></div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for element in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "plc-product-date___1zgO_"}):
   print(element.get_text(strip=True))
...
>>> Thursday 01 Jul 00:00
```

Comment: would there be a more general way of doing it, I would like to apply the solution to other similar elements with the <strong> tag.

Comment: If you want to get texts inside all <strong> tags, simply replace the div in find_all with strong. `soup.find_all("strong"):`
Otherwise, you need to first collect all elements you are interested in. Based on the tag, classes, the element's ID, or child elements. E.g. to iterate comments which cannot be collected by their classes, retrieve their parent div and then iterate its children.